# Raspberry Pi bluetooth volume buttons

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have configured my pi to connect and receive bluetooth audio from my iPhone 5c using pulseaudio and bluez. How do I use my volume buttons from my iPhone to control the output of the audio from my pi? I'm running Jessie on my raspberry pi zero.

Edit: I followed this tutorial: https://gist.github.com/oleq/24e09112b07464acbda1

Answer (score 1):

You either use global hotkey daemon like `triggerhappy` or load pulseaudio module `module-mmkbd-evdev` with corresponding Bluetooth input device from `/dev/input/`